# C++ expression must have integral or unscoped enum type on %

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

In this code I have defined the remainder in this code as float data type but the compiler rejected that and suppose to defien it as an inegral type what is the reasone for this issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54CIx.png)

```cpp
int main()
{

    float days, hours, minutes, seconds;
    float Totalseconds;
    float Remainder;
    float secondsperday;
    float secondsperhour;
    float secondsperminute;

    secondsperday = 24 * 60 * 60;
    secondsperhour = 60 * 60;
    secondsperminute = 60;


    cout << "Enter total seconds\n";
    cin >> Totalseconds;

    days = floor(Totalseconds / secondsperday);
    Remainder = (Totalseconds % secondsperday);

    hours = floor(Remainder / secondsperhour);
    Remainder = Remainder % secondsperhour;

    minutes = floor(Remainder / secondsperminute);
    Remainder = Remainder % secondsperminute;

    seconds = Remainder;

    cout << days << ":" << hours << ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, [don't post your code/error messages as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). Firstly we want to copy/paste it and secondly search engines are unable to index that information. So please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form.

Comment: *expression must have **integral** or unscoped enum type on %* - what don't you understand there? Are `Totalseconds ` and `secondsperday` and other integral types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> expression must have integral or unscoped enum type on %

Floating-point numbers like `float` don't have a `%` operator in C++.
They are neither integral (i.e. integers like `int`) nor unscoped enumerations (i.e. `enum`), so you're getting this error.

If you wanted a floating-point remainder that works similarly to `%` operator, you could use [`std::fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod):

```cpp
Remainder = std::fmod(Totalseconds, secondsperday);
```

However, in your code, it looks like none of the numbers have to be `float` (unless `Totalseconds` can be 123.456 for example).
If you simply changed all of the `float` types to `int`, this code would also compile.